# How to get the dropdown nav child elements to follow the parent position from top

Tags: jquery, html, css

Progress and what I want to do should be clear here:

https://codepen.io/RautSamir/pen/RjzEKY

Under Offices, I need the child objects to show right under and hopefully same width as parent.

code:

```
    <div class="navItem" style="display:inline">
<button class="dropbtn"> Home </button>
</div>

<div class="dropdown" style="display:inline">
<button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Offices</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#home">Regional</a>
    <a href="#about">Global</a>
    <a href="#contact">Local</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="navItem" style="display:inline">
<button class="dropbtn"> Who we are</button>
</div>

<div class="navItem" style="display:inline">
<button class="dropbtn"> Contact </button>
</div>

<div class="navItem" style="display:inline">
<button class="dropbtn" id="searchBox"> Search </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The changes made :

- Setting width to 100%(you can adjust the size and reduce it to 97,98 so the additional padding isn't in effect and it looks perfectly aligned to the action button) and removing min-width from dropdown content.
- Using left:0 so that the dropdown gets aligned with respect to parent element.
- The offices parent div should also have the class of "navItem" since its one of the rest of your inline buttons.

Codepen : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YEodjR

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 19.5%;
}

.dropbtn:hover,
.dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: black;
  text-style: bold;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  width: 98%;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="navItem" style="display:inline">
  <button class="dropbtn"> Home </button>
</div>

<div class="navItem dropdown" style="display:inline">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Offices</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#home">Regional</a>
    <a href="#about">Global</a>
    <a href="#contact">Local</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="navItem" style="display:inline">
  <button class="dropbtn"> Who we are</button>
</div>

<div class="navItem" style="display:inline">
  <button class="dropbtn"> Contact </button>
</div>

<div class="navItem" style="display:inline">
  <button class="dropbtn" id="searchBox"> Search </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! That did it :)

Comment: @zigzag No problem.

Answer (score 0):

Define the `left` position as zero (relative to it's parent, not the window).

To make it as width as it's parent, use `right: 0`.

You'll notice a 4px difference, that's because of the inline-block on the parent. You can fix that by setting the right position to 4px.

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 19.5%;
}

.dropbtn:hover,
.dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: black;
  /*invalid
  text-style: bold;*/
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}


.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  overflow: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="navItem" style="display:inline">
  <button class="dropbtn"> Home </button>
</div>

<div class="dropdown" style="display:inline">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Offices</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#home">Regional</a>
    <a href="#about">Global</a>
    <a href="#contact">Local</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="navItem" style="display:inline">
  <button class="dropbtn"> Who we are</button>
</div>

<div class="navItem" style="display:inline">
  <button class="dropbtn"> Contact </button>
</div>

<div class="navItem" style="display:inline">
  <button class="dropbtn" id="searchBox"> Search </button>
</div>
```

Comment: @zigzag, check here https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Answer (score 0):

1) You have set the parents to display as inline so that everything aligns next to each other.

2) Change that to inline-block and you will see the drop-down lines up.
I'd advise you look into display types and get an understanding of how they each behave. At that point, it should become a lot more useful to you

3) Then the width on the buttons needs to be removed so that the button is not cut off. Rather set the width on the parents and have the button and drop-down widths set to 100%. They will then take the parents full width.

That should do it.

Comment: Thanks for the input. positioning and display types can def help me with some css wizardry. Will look them up..